# Can't find DOM with document.getElementById in IE8

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, getelementbyid

I am trying to get a handle on a DOM by using document.getElementById("my_id") but not able to.
There are two stages in my code flow:
Stage 1 (works):

```
document.getElementById("my_text_field").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("my_text_field").style.display= "none";
```

I don't know which one of the above ones get executed.

Stage 2 (does not work):

```
document.getElementById("my_text_field").style.visibility = "visible";
```

or

```
document.getElementById("my_text_field").style.display = "table-row";
```

Both the stages are working fine in Firefox 3.6 (I have to use 3.6).
But it seems like in stage 1 the DOM is getting hidden/invisible and therefore, IE8 can't find them using document.getElementById().

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to hide and display some of the div elements based on condition?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is [`table-row` support in IE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp):

> The values "inline-table", "run-in", "table", "table-caption", "table-cell", "table-column", "table-column-group", "table-row", "table-row-group", and "inherit" is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Comment: I checked and I do have the tag: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: I also checked on the IE8 javascript console, the DOM itself is not being found. So, document.getElementById() returns nothing. When I tried disabling stage 1, stage 2 was working fine. But I do need a way to 'hide' the text field.

Comment: Are you sure you are running in IE8 mode and not 7?

Comment: Yes, I am sure I am running in IE8 mode.